# creal and cimag problems with Clang 3.4

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c11, petsc

I am compiling a library with Petsc using Clang 3.4 and get:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'creal'
```

it follows from the following define:

```
petscmath.h:121:38: note: expanded from macro 'PetscRealPartComplex'
#define PetscRealPartComplex(a)      creal(a)
```

the only relevant info i can find is [this](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=170455), i don't know if this is something compiler-specific and some libraries are missing or i have some problems with Petsc.

I tried using `cimag()' as it is in a small test file, but i can't compile it with neither clang3.4 nor gcc4.8.

Anyone has any ideas what is happening. Google does not show any similar topics...

**EDIT**:

so here is a simple example:

```
#include <complex.h>
int main ()
{
   double complex z;
   double cc = cimag(z);
}
```

it *does* compile with Gcc4.8 (from macports): `g++-mp-4.8 main.cc -o main`

however in c11 mode it *does not* : `g++-mp-4.8 -std=c++11 main.cc -o main`:

```
expected initializer before 'z' double complex z;
```

clang *does not* compile it in either cases and produce the same error as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7999959899/basedefs/complex.h.html

> The  header shall define the following macros:
>
> complex
>
> ```
>     Expands to _Complex.
> ```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex

> If the macro constant **STDC_NO_COMPLEX**(C11) is defined by the
>   compiler, the header  and all of the names listed here are
>   not provided.

Note that I get the same results when specifying `-std=c++11` with GCC, but *not* `-x c -std=c11`. YMMV.

Comment: do i understand you correctly that cimag/creal are defined only for C, not C++? Thus the code compiles only as C via, e.g., `clang++-mp-3.4 -x c main.cc -o main`?

Comment: @Denis Only if `STDC_NO_COMPLEX` is defined by the compiler. I don't think it's a C vs C++ thing.